# MySQL fetching: need some advice

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to fetch information from a single table wherein I'm going to display latest transaction per record, and at the same time record from it's previous transaction.

## Table:

```
|id | account_no | date1      | price |
|1  | 101        |2018-04-10  | 100   |
|2  | 101        |2018-04-7   | 200   |
|3  | 102        |2018-04-10  | 300   |
```

## Output should look something like this:

```
|account_no|latest_entry(date)|price |previous_entry(date)|price |
|101       |2018-04-10        |100   |2018-04-7           |200   |
|102       |2018-04-10        |300   |null                |0     |
```

This is my query:

```
select max(date_recorded) as ldte, test_tbl.* from test_tbl group by account_no order by date_recorded desc
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a reference to the previous information by doing:

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.id
        from t t2
        where t2.account_no = t.account_no and t2.date1 < t.date1
        order by t2.date1 desc
        limit 1
       ) as prev_id
from t ;
```

Use this as a subquery to join back to the original table:

```
select t.*, tprev.date, tprev.price
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.id
              from t t2
              where t2.account_no = t.account_no and t2.date1 < t.date1
              order by t2.date1 desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_id
      from t
     ) t join
     t tprev
     on t.prev_id = tprev.id;
```

You can limit this to the most recent date by adding the following `where` clause:

```
where t.id = (select t2.id
              from t t2
              where t2.account_no = t.account_no
              order by t2.date desc
              limit 1
             )
```

This can go either in the outer query or in the subquery.

Comment: Thanks for this one, it helps a lot, now the only problem is if there's only one record for an account. if there's 2 date recorded for 1 account it display everything properly, but if there's only one date record it does not display any record.
Thank you very much for these one greatly appreciated.